# auto calculate total sum based on discount amounts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm doing some calculations of the total cost of items in an array that would be displayed in the HTML, the total sum should be such that when making the calculations, it should consider the `discount amount` against `each row` and add up together before it `sums` up all the rows total to make the total sum.

data

```
costItems = [
{
    name: 'Corn Flakes'
    unitPrice: 9,
    quantity: 10,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 10
},
{
    name: 'Sugar'
    unitPrice: 5,
    quantity: 10,
    hasDiscount: true,
    discountPercentage: 10
},
{
    name: 'Bread'
    unitPrice: 2,
    quantity: 7,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 0
},
{
    name: 'Salt'
    unitPrice: 1,
    quantity: 4,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 0
}
]
```

Current Code I have

```
   calculateTotalSum() {
        this.totalSum = this.costItems.reduce((sum, {unitPrice, quantity}) => sum += unitPrice * quantity, 0);
console.log(this.totalSum)
      }
```

This works by calculating the total sum ignoring the discount amounts but what I want to do is to consider the discounts in there

Comment: Do you want to calculate total value for the data who is having only 'hasDiscount' flag true? or something else? Please elaborate some more with some basic scenario or either put the formula for which you want result, so that is is makes us easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const costItems = [
    {
        name: 'Corn Flakes',
        unitPrice: 9,
        quantity: 10,
        hasDiscount: false,
        discountPercentage: 10,
    },
    {
        name: 'Sugar',
        unitPrice: 5,
        quantity: 10,
        hasDiscount: true,
        discountPercentage: 10,
    },
    {
        name: 'Bread',
        unitPrice: 2,
        quantity: 7,
        hasDiscount: false,
        discountPercentage: 0,
    },
    {
        name: 'Salt',
        unitPrice: 1,
        quantity: 4,
        hasDiscount: false,
        discountPercentage: 0,
    },
];

const totalSum = costItems.reduce(
    (sum, { unitPrice, quantity, discountPercentage }) =>
        (sum += unitPrice * quantity * (1 - discountPercentage / 100)),
    0,
);

console.log(totalSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
let costItems = [{
    name: 'Corn Flakes',
    unitPrice: 9,
    quantity: 10,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Sugar',
    unitPrice: 5,
    quantity: 10,
    hasDiscount: true,
    discountPercentage: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Bread',
    unitPrice: 2,
    quantity: 7,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Salt',
    unitPrice: 1,
    quantity: 4,
    hasDiscount: false,
    discountPercentage: 0
  }
];

let sum = costItems.reduce((acc, val) => acc += (val.quantity * val.unitPrice) * ((100 - val.discountPercentage) / 100), 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: _In question, you have not used reduce in the correct way_ What's wrong?